# Need to select rows from the table with a version column which match the latest version

Tags: sql, performance

What is the best way to do this in SQL (Sybase SQL if the distinctions matter):

**Table:** (with some sample data)

```
| id | value1 | value2 | version |
==================================
| 1  | A11    | B11    | 1       | 
| 1  | A12    | B12    | 2       | 
| 2  | A21    | B21    | 1       | 
| 3  | A32    | B32    | 2       | 

Unique key: (id, version). Index: (id, version)
```

**Dataset size:** ~100k rows in the table, with the typical query's where clause restricting the results to 10-100 ids and version #s being 1,2 or sometimes 3.

**What I need to do:** for every ID, retrieve the row with the highest version for that ID

```
| id | value1 | value2 | version |
==================================
| 1  | A12    | B12    | 2       | <---- Chosen since 2>1 for id=1
| 2  | A21    | B21    | 1       | 
| 3  | A32    | B32    | 2       |
```

**Simple solution:** The obvious way I can think of is to use sub-query:

```
SELECT  id, value1, value2
FROM    T   'T1'
WHERE   id in (1, 2, 3, ... 10)  -- Obviously a fake sample clause
 AND    version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM T 'T2' 
                   WHERE T1.id=T2.id
                    AND  id in (1, 2, 3, ... 10)
                  )
```

**Question: Is this the best approach?**

"Best" here means:

1. "best performing on average" (given dataset size, typical query size and indexes shown above).
2. For approaches with similar performance, most elegant code-wise. This is in the eye of the beholder obviously, but if you can show that the code is more extensible/maintainable, that is a clear indication of elegant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          value1, 
          value2, 
          version,
          max(version) over (partition by id) as max_version
    FROM T
    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ... 10)
) t2
WHERE version = max_version
```

Depending on your DBMS (especially the optimizer) and indexes this might be faster than the sub-select as only a single scan over the table is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `JOIN` instead of subquery makes it more readable:

```
SELECT  id, value1, value2
FROM    T   'T1'
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id,MAX(version) as version 
  FROM T 
  WHERE id IN (...)
  GROUP BY id) T2
 ON (T1.id = T2.id AND T1.version=T2.version)
WHERE   T1.id in (1, 2, 3, ... 10)
```

It should not cause any performance overhead/benefits compared to the original query.